# How to link images of one WP site to another WP site?

Tags: categories, images, attachments

My first site is having 92 categories to display more than 10,000 SMS. Now I want to insert random images to all my posts (SMS) from my other site which is having images as per my categories in SMS site.

I want to code in such a way: Put some code in category file on the first site and it will fetch images from a category of the second site and display any random image to all posts.

All 92 SMS categories will be linked to different categories of Images to display relevant images for the same.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Move your images into a Content Delivery Network (CDN) so they are external to the site. Then you can pull them into any number of sites.

Look at something like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Cloudflare](http://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn).

Comment: How will that incorporate the OPs request to make use of WP categories?

Comment: @JohannesPille My question is that, how can I display different images from one gallery of my WP site into different SMS page of another WP site? My facebook4free site is having all images in next-gen gallery plugin, from which I want to display images to my single pages of freesmsbook site.